# Media Foundation : Looping video unstable on 6th run

Tags: loops, ms-media-foundation

Took current media foundation sample from github (MF_ProtectedPlayback, but could have been one of the others).

Added the following so it loops when it gets to the end :

```
CPlayer::HandleEvent()
{

     case MEEndOfPresentation:
            CHECK_HR(hr = OnPresentationEnded(pEvent));

            // ADV_SW: Loop.
            {
               static DWORD dbg_count = 0;
               dbg_count++;
               char title[100];
               sprintf_s(title, "Loop: %d", dbg_count);
               SetWindowTextA(m_hwndEvent, title);
            }

            Play();
            break;
        }
```

Also, in CPlayer::StartPlayback

... modified so second play starts from beginning

```
    // Start from beginning 
    PROPVARIANT varStart = { 0 };
    InitPropVariantFromInt64(0, &varStart);
    hr = m_pSession->Start(&GUID_NULL, &varStart);
```

When I play example file http://advance-software.com/misc/ad.mp4  (download & run locally)

It works fine for first 5 loops, then starts breaking up on the 6th.

Anyone know what's up ?

Thanks in advance,
Steve.

Comment: Tested Win 10 Home / 64 Insider Preview.

Build: 21343.rs-prerelease.210320-1757

Comment: Tried same with MFPlayer2 sample, which loops correctly, however the interface is too basic for needs as topology is hidden inside black box & need to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you must call

m_pSession->Stop();

before the Start() when looping to ensure stability.

Surprised this doesn't occur internally if a requirement to ensure API robustness but such are the dark arts of Media Foundation :)